# Como somar um determinado valor a um Integer de um JSON em vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, json.net

Olá, eu tenho este código:

```
    Imports System.IO
    Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
    Public Class Form1
        Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
            Dim channel As JObject = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("C:\stats.json"))
            Dim points = channel.GetValue("points").ToString()

            Label1.Text = points
        End Sub
```

E eu tenho um botão, que, no caso, quero que a cada vez que ele é apertado, sejam adicionados +30 no `points`.
Como fazer isso? Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: O único local onde tem o valor do `points` é numa `Label`? Não tem uma classe onde armazene isso?

Comment: Não, existe um módulo. Mas quero que, ao clicar no botão, sejam adicionado mais 30 points no JSON.

Comment: Ha, no JSON! Ou seja, quer pegar no objeto que veio do seu ficheiro JSON, adicionar 30 e depois voltar a gravar o ficheiro mas com o `points` atualizado? É isso?

Comment: Sim! É isso mesmo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimente fazer da seguinte forma:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim channel As JObject = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("C:\stats.json"))

        With channel
            'Adicionar 30 pontos
            .Item("points") = Convert.ToInt32(.Item("points")) + 30
        End With

        'Serializar o objeto
        Dim result As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(channel)

        File.WriteAllText("C:\stats.json", result)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Ocorreu um erro: " + ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```